# How to receive emails using flutter (or dart)?

Tags: email, flutter, dart

I want to receive emails using flutter, but I didn't find any good external package to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by receive email? Are you looking for creating your own email client?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I want to, for a given email address show the emails received to that particular email address.

Answer (score 1):

I could only find [imap_client](https://pub.dev/packages/imap_client) on the pub.dev site, and is in alpha state.
Maybe you can find some POP3 libs around or maybe look for native libs to create some basic interfase, and avoid all the Sockets code mess :)